# PHP referencing functions not in a script

Tags: javascript, php

Can somebody please explain to me where can PHP script get this functions from, I have a PHP script that has this few lines:

```
<?php
$args1 = array();
$gethosts = get_xml_host_objects($args1); //grabbing internal xml data from backend

$args2 = array();
$gethoststatus = get_xml_host_status($args2);

$args3 = array();
$getparenthosts = get_xml_host_parents($args3);
```

So I do not understand from where and how could this PHP script be referencing those functions, could somebody just give me few examples suggestions of where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, there is a file that includes the two scripts. Somethings like that

```
<?php
    include 'file_with_function.php';
    include 'your_file.php';
?>
```

These lines can help. Place them at the beginning of your file

```
echo '<pre>';  
debug_print_backtrace();  
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: So to explain it from the beginning this script that I have quoted is the script that gets called by the initial script through javascript include statement and that all work fine.
What I want to do is call that same script through Ajax request, so that I can use SetInterval function, but when I try that I start getting those errors.

Comment: Now I tried putting:
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../componenthelper.inc.php');
on the start of the second called script, in front of the stated code, but it did not help, it just came with a bunch of different errors instead of complaining that it can not find get_xml_host_objects function.
So my final question is why is that happening?
How is javascript include different from ajax request?
Why is the called function complain when I did put the same include in it like it is in the script that is calling it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like those were self defined functions, maybe you can try grep thru entire source tree to see if which .php file define these functions and include it in this script.

Comment: How does one "grep through entire source tree"?